# What happens when I launch AWS Cloudformation and log out of my account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

So, what happens when I launch AWS Cloudformation and log out of my account? Will the process continue running or will it stop? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process itself is being executed by the AWS CloudFormation service, not your individual session.

So to confirm yes it will proceed with the rollout whether you're logged in or logged out.

In fact if you think about running it via a CLI command there is never a session that persists after the initial execution, and all the console is doing is running a GUI on top of the native AWS APIs